# What is the dimension of this subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $(w,x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^4$. Determine a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$  formed by the intersection of the plane $x+y-w+z=0$  with the plane $2x-y+2w-z=0$  ?  What is the dimension of this subspace?

Comment: What have you tried? This is a site intended to *help* you with homework, not do it all for you.

Comment: i need to learn how to determine basis of subspace of R^n and i know this site wont solve it for me, but i though some1 will show me the way to solve it so i could understend about this finding dimension or determining basis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the first plan by $P_1$, the second by $P_2.$
Then $p=(w,x,y,z)\in P_1\iff w=x+y+z,$ and $p\in P_2\iff y+z=2(x+w).$
Hence $p\in P:=P_1\cap P_2\iff \begin{cases}w=3x+2w\\y+z=2(x+w)\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}w=-3x\\y+z=-4x\end{cases}.$
Therefore a basis for $P$ is given by $p_1=(-3,1,-4,0), p_2=(-3,1,0,-4):$
If $w=-3x$ and $y+z=-4x,$ then $(w,x,y,z)=\frac{-y}{4}p_1+\frac{-z}{4}p_2.$
And $p_1$ and $p_2$ are linearly independant.
Intuitively, these are two planes of dimension $3,$ and they intersect in a plane of fimension $2.$
Hope this helps.